# depth-first-search/breadth-first-search easy implementation

Tags: java, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

```
List<Tree<T>> unvisited = node.getChildren();
```

DFS:

```
while (!unvisited.isEmpty()) {
   Tree<T> node = unvisited.remove(0);
   //search node
   unvisited.addAll(0, node.getChildren());
}
```

BFS:

```
while (!unvisited.isEmpty()) {
   Tree<T> node = unvisited.remove(0);
   //search node
   unvisited.addAll(node.getChildren());
}
```

Are these implementations too simple to be true? Was wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: @jlordo sorry I missed the declaration above. Just ignore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these implementations too simple to be true? Was wondering if I'm
>   missing something?

Your implementations are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Unless limited to only acyclic graphs, you are going to end up with duplicate nodes in the unvisited List since you have not marked the visited nodes. You need to iterate over List of children and mark them visited before adding to the tree.

BFS Pseudocode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode

Also you might want to consider using a Deque in place of List. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Comment: Yes, the above implementations were only for acyclic graphs. Your answer, however, has revealed the required modifications for extension to cyclic graphs as well. Thanks!